# Subdomain to a subfolder in the main domain server

Tags: apache, dns, virtualhost, amazon-route53

I have a domain hosted in an Amazon EC2 instance and DNS configuration managed with Route 53. This domain is "example.com" with this apache VirtualHost config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin admin@example.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
ServerName example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

I want to create a subdomain "hi.example.com" that point to a subfolder in the same server as the document root.

**What I have tried:**

I created an A record as an alias with the name "hi.example.com" and a the value of the A record of the main domain "example.com" that points to my EC2 ellastic IP and a VirtualHost config like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/hi/
ServerName hi.example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

But that cause my "hi.example.com" goes to "hi.example.com/hi" and no finding nothing.

I want "hi.example.com" stay as the url in the browser and goes to subfolder in that subfolder writting the URL like a normal domain like "hi.example.com/page1","hi.example.com/page2", etc...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried following the instruction here:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/CreatingNewSubdomain.html

Comment: Yes, I tried but I dont know if it is my virtualhost configuration but that doesnt make what I want.